# View number of nodes used in Hive queries

Tags: azure, hive, mapreduce, azure-hdinsight

I need to view the number of nodes used in my HDinsights cluster while running hive queries. How can i view this while running my queries. I know Ambari view provides this, but where can i get the exact number of nodes and storage used. Thanks

Comment: You need to extract the YARN job ID from the Hive logs _(when using custom code with JDBC/ODBC it's a bit tricky because Hive does not use the usual channel for async notification)_ then check the job status in YARN ResourceManager UI -- or via command line `yarn application -status <id>`

Comment: Beware, `job_xxxxxx_xxxx` is the legacy naming convention for job IDs (still used by the legacy Job HistoryServer shipping with Cloudera), the RM uses instead `application_xxxxxx_xxxx`

Comment: The detail of container placement is visible in RM under the current "attempt" -- or when the job is over, it can be extracted from the headers of each archived log in HistoryServer / TimelineServer

Answer (score 0):

After you run the job, review the current Jobtracker log and you may see entries like this -

```
2014-01-23 20:14:59,136 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Input size for job job_201401221948_0006 = 1395667. Number of splits = 7
2014-01-23 20:14:59,137 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: tip:task_201401221948_0006_m_000000 has split on node:/fd0/ud0/localhost
2014-01-23 20:14:59,137 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: tip:task_201401221948_0006_m_000001 has split on node:/fd0/ud0/localhost
```

......

**If you see Number of splits=1, there will be one map task and you know that only node will be utilized.**

**and when Number of splits > 1, for each split you will see a map task created with Tasktracker node info like this -**

```
2014-01-23 20:14:59,153 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Adding task (JOB_SETUP) 'attempt_201401221948_0006_m_000008_0' to tip task_201401221948_0006_m_000008, for tracker 'tracker_workernode7:127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:49200'
```

Comment: Thanks Mayank.But I'm looking for option of checking how many nodes did my single hive query used for processing.

Comment: Thanks Mayank. So how come input splits will be equivalent to the number of nodes. I can have one input split which can be stored into two different nodes.

Comment: I have a two node cluster with 256 MB size each and have a input file with 512 MB and my block and input split size is 128 MB. So when I run this file
it will be splitted into four different blocks (each of 128 MB) and 4 input splits. So in this case 4 input splits will not count for 4 different nodes. 

Hope my question is clear.